# ASP.NET MVC - ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText: Returning wrong property name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, expression, mvccontrib

My view uses MVCContrib Grid and I need some input fields within it:

```
@(Html.Grid(Model.Items)
.RenderUsing(new PostAsListRenderer<ItemModel>("list"))
.Columns(c =>
{
    c.Custom(
        @<text>
             @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.Id), item.Id)
             @item.Id
         </text>
    ).Named("Id");
    c.For(x => Html.TextBoxFor(y => x.Name)).Named("Name");
    c.For(x => Html.TextBoxFor(y => x.Description)).Named("Description");
    c.For(x => Html.DropDownListFor(y => x.SelectedItem, Model.SelectListItems)).Named("DropDown");
    c.For(x => Html.NameFor(y => x.Name));
}))
```

The problem is that the name attribute for the text box is:

**list[38ef6173-b837-4d5a-ab2a-28ba9989c879].Value.Name**

instead of

**list[38ef6173-b837-4d5a-ab2a-28ba9989c879].Name**.

**list[38ef6173-b837-4d5a-ab2a-28ba9989c879]** is a prefix created by my custom renderer `PostAsListRenderer` that uses `TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix`.

**.Name** is created within ASP.NET MVC by `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText`.

The problem occurs for all input fields.

I need the correct name values for posting the whole grid to the server.

The problem is the kind of expression I use `c.For(x => Html.TextBoxFor(y => x.Name))`.

Is this a bug in the `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText` method?

By now I have a workaround, that is only working for non complex properties:

```
@(Html.Grid(Model.Items)
.RenderUsing(new PostAsListRenderer<ItemModel>("list"))
.Columns(c =>
{
    c.Custom(
        @<text>
             @Html.Hidden(Reflector.GetPropertyName(x => item.Id), item.Id)
             @item.Id
         </text>
    ).Named("Id");
    c.For(x => Html.TextBox(Reflector.GetPropertyName(y => x.Name), x.Name)).Named("Name");
    c.For(x => Html.TextBox(Reflector.GetPropertyName(y => x.Description), x.Description)).Named("Description");
    c.For(x => Html.DropDownList(Reflector.GetPropertyName(y => x.SelectedItem), Model.SelectListItems)).Named("DropDown");
}))
```

Is there a better way of creating correct name attribute values?

**Edit #1:**

In my opinion this is a bug. If you think so too, vote up the issue at: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/638

**Edit #2:**
Those are my view models:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<ItemModel> Items { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> SelectListItems { get; set; }
}

public class ItemModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The code is also available at: https://github.com/Rookian/ListModelBinding

Comment: what does your model class look like?